# joining clusters using depth/breadth first search in python

Tags: python, set, cluster-computing, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm doing a small python project about finding clusters. I've read http://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/ and used the depth first search in my code to generate the list of cluster, but now I want to do join two clusters once I have found a new point connecting the two.

Suppose I have:

```
graph1 = {'A': set(['B', 'C']),
     'B': set(['A', 'D', 'E']),
     'C': set(['A', 'F']),
     'D': set(['B']),
     'E': set(['B', 'F']),
     'F': set(['C', 'E'])
     'G': set(['H', 'I']),
     'H': set(['G'),
     'I': set(['G', 'J']),
     'J': set(['I'])}
```

Using depth first search, I can easily find two separate clusters `[A,B,C,D,E,F]` and `[G,H,I,J]`.

Now suppose I have a new element `'K':set(['F','G'])`, so K is connected to F and G. Because of the point K, the two clusters are now joined together to form a new big cluster `[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K]`. How do I do it systematically using depth/breadth first search or other algorithms (as I will keep adding new points and test if the new point can join or even combine any existing clusters)?

thanks

Comment: "How do I do *it* systematically using depth/breadth first search or other algorithms ... ?" How do you do **what exactly**? Wouldn't all clusters that have members in the new point be joined?

Comment: You mean running the depth first search again for all the points? That will of course return one single big cluster, but now suppose I have two separate clusters and a new point (which can link the two existing clusters to form a big cluster). I want to check if the point to see if it links to any existing cluster (which is yes in this case), and if two formally clusters are now connected because of the new point, then combine those two clusters. I want to do it WITHOUT performing depth-first search for ALL the points again.

Comment: Basically, what I want to do is to write a program that can constantly take in new point and check its connection with existing clusters EFFICIENTLY, because I will keep adding (over a hundred or even thousands of )new points to the, and I want to make the program run as fast as possible.